# Spark job writing into Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

Spark job is taking ~36 Min for ~32 Million records to load oracle data into cassandra.
Spark 1.6.2 with Scala.
Can someone help on right settings in write to cassandra.

```
      spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows
      spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes
      spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes
```

I see some below INFO messages from Master.

> INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:34,911
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Connected to
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,494
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,502
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,511
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,525
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,528
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,533
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,543
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,543
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,546
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster INFO  2018-03-01 07:55:37,547
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from
>   Cassandra cluster: OCP-Cluster

Comment: please show the code that is used for writing, and other details.

Comment: What is your exact problem? Does it write to slow? Data are missing? Cassandra is not performing as you expect it? Doesn't it work at all? You will not get any answer if you are not comming with a concrete problem. Furthermore you should provide at least the code you use to build up your pipeline. Oracle schema and cassandra schema and some example data are also quite helpful.